# Lync 2013 dropped calls after 5 min

Tags: lync, lync-2013

I have a problem with call dropped after 5 min ( during mute "on" ). If mute is "on" RTP packets will not flow from Lync server. Do you know how to force Lync to sent "empty" RTP packets during mute in enabled ?

PS. Current fix its not working :

```
Set-CsTrunkConfiguration -EnableSessionTimer $True 
Set-CsTrunkConfiguration -RTCPActiveCalls $false -RTCPCallsOnHold $false
```

Comment: You do not have some Scooper logs here which give more infos or?